# How can I perform an n way ANOVA in python?

Tags: python-3.x, statistics

I'd like to perform N-way ANOVA (specifically 4-way) in python, but most of what I see focuses on one or two way ANOVA. I know nothing about R so I'd prefer to not have to migrate there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One good way is to use [statsmodel anova](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/anova.html). With this software you can specify models in more or less the conventional way using the [patsy language](https://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/v0.1.0/formulas.html), and results are presented as you would expect.